# Problem compiling and linking voxelyze library

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I'm rather new in c++, and I've just installed Ubuntu in my windows PC a few weeks ago.

I have to work with a static library called Voxelyze (I downloaded it from [Here](https://github.com/jonhiller/Voxelyze). There you can see where are the includes, libs and makefile). And I'm trying to compile an example code (I named it testeo.cpp).

My testeo.cpp path is: c/Users/Familia/Desktop/MEMORIA/F/galib247/galib247/examples

And the voxelyze library path is: c/Users/Familia/Desktop/MEMORIA/F/galib247/galib247/examples/Voxelyze-master

This is the code:

```
#include "Voxelyze.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout << "Testing voxelyze library\n";
  CVoxelyze Vx(0.005); //5mm voxels
  CVX_Material* pMaterial = Vx.addMaterial(1000000, 1000); //A material with stiffness E=1MPa and density 1000Kg/m^3
  CVX_Voxel* Voxel1 = Vx.setVoxel(pMaterial, 0, 0, 0); //Voxel at index x=0, y=0, z=0
  CVX_Voxel* Voxel2 = Vx.setVoxel(pMaterial, 1, 0, 0);
  CVX_Voxel* Voxel3 = Vx.setVoxel(pMaterial, 2, 0, 0); //Beam extends in the +X direction
  Voxel1->external()->setFixedAll(); //Fixes all 6 degrees of freedom with an external condition on Voxel 1
  Voxel3->external()->setForce(0, 0, -1); //pulls Voxel 3 downward with 1 Newton of force.

  for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
    Vx.doTimeStep(); //simulate 100 timesteps.
    cout << "Current position: " << (float)Voxel3->position().z << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This code simply puts three voxels in a row, excerts a downward force in the third one, and then simulates its behavior, and for each timestep simulation it shows its displacement.

Ok, now, in my ubuntu command (after doing sudo apt-get -y update, sudo apt-get -y upgrade and sudo apt-get install build-essential) I firstly go to the voxelyze directory and I do "make clean" and then "make", so that it makes everything that needs to be made:

```
$ cd /mnt/c/Users/Familia/Desktop/MEMORIA/F/galib247/galib247/examples/Voxelyze-master
$ make clean
$ make
```

So far so good.

Then, I return to my testeo.cpp path by simply doing cd .. and, using GCC, I try to compile testeo.cpp this way:

```
$ cd..
$ g++ -Wall -o testeo testeo.cpp -I./Voxelyze-master/include -L./Voxelyze-master/lib/ -lvoxelyze.0.9
```

But I get the following error message:

```
testeo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
testeo.cpp:15:14: warning: unused variable ‘Voxel2’ [-Wunused-variable]
   15 |   CVX_Voxel* Voxel2 = Vx.setVoxel(pMaterial, 1, 0, 0);
      |              ^~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: ./Voxelyze-master/lib//libvoxelyze.0.9.a(VX_LinearSolver.o): in function `CVX_LinearSolver::CVX_LinearSolver(CVoxelyze*)':
VX_LinearSolver.cpp:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to `pardisoinit'
/usr/bin/ld: ./Voxelyze-master/lib//libvoxelyze.0.9.a(VX_LinearSolver.o): in function `CVX_LinearSolver::solve()':
VX_LinearSolver.cpp:(.text+0x2a13): undefined reference to `pardiso'
/usr/bin/ld: VX_LinearSolver.cpp:(.text+0x2b17): undefined reference to `pardiso'
/usr/bin/ld: VX_LinearSolver.cpp:(.text+0x2c26): undefined reference to `pardiso'
/usr/bin/ld: VX_LinearSolver.cpp:(.text+0x2e30): undefined reference to `pardiso'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Well I don't care much about the warning message, but about the "undefined reference to error".

I think it's an internal library error, (or maybe I'm doing something wrong in my linkage, IDK) because it's complaining about some "LinearSolver" class functions and a "pardiso" thing... but I'm not using them in my testeo.cpp code (at least not directly).

Well, I don't know how to make this thing work, and my engineering degree is on the line here hahaha.

I hope you can help me here, I'd thank you a lot. I'm rather new in this C++-Linux world, but whatever additional information you need in order to solve this mystery, I'll try to do my best to help.

Thanks.

Comment: A static library is nothing more than an archive of object files, and using a static library is similar to listing the object files themselves. This means that whatever additional library that the static library depends on *also* needs to be linked with. So you need to link with the `voxelyze` libraries dependencies as well.

Comment: Hi programmer dude, in first place, thank you a lot for answering. But, how can I see what libraries Voxelyze depends on? Do I have to search on every file or some specific place?

Comment: ok @Someprogrammerdude, I was reading the Linear Solver header file and I found this:  `#ifdef PARDISO_5
#ifdef _WIN32
        #pragma comment (lib, "libpardiso500-WIN-X86-64.lib") //link to the Pardiso library
#endif`  So, I have to link that library ... Do I have to download, install or something first?

Comment: Read up on linking, it's simple.

Comment: I have read a lot about linking, but now I have a lot of questions related to the version of pardiso. I'll be following this on other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64174369/how-do-i-link-libpardiso600-in-a-library-that-requires-a-libpardiso500